# How do you put the output of a for loop to a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

If I take a take a simple for loop as an example:

```
for num in range(0,6)
print(num)
```

it gives me:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

How can I get the output as a list, like this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

If I do this:

```
lst = []
for num in range(0,6):
    lst.append(num)
    print(lst)
```

I get:

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Six lists, but I only want the last one.

Comment: Just put the `print` *after* your `for` loop instead of inside it.

Comment: why are you printing list in each iteration?

Comment: *"Six lists, but I only want the last one."* No... You have one list, you just print it six times

Comment: Please review the role of indentation in Python, and carefully proofread your code before posting a new question.

Comment: This is not actually a question about how to make the list. It is a question about understanding what `print` does, and perhaps what `return` does (if the code is inside a function). `lst` **already** contains the value you want; using `print` is **completely unrelated** to that.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `list` to make it a list:

```
print(list(range(6)))
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Your code doesn't work because:

- Because you `print` every time the loop is going again, so actually your code works if you make `print(lst)` outside of the loop
- Your final list is actually your expected list, I'm telling you.

Comment: This doesn't explain what the problem was.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I hope i explained now.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do using `list-comprehension`

```
print([i for i in range(6)])
```

**What's wrong with your code**

- First you are trying to print individual elements where you want
  output as list
- In 2nd attempt you just misplaced the print statement inside the loop
  while it should be outside the `for loop`.

Comment: This doesn't explain what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

after completing your for loop then use print

```
lst = []
for num in range(0,6):
    lst.append(num)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is your current code

```
lst = []
for num in range(0,6):
    lst.append(num)
    print(lst)
```

As you can see your `print(lst)` statement is indented *inside* the loop so it prints `lst` every `num in range(0,6)`. To fix this, move it outside the loop so you only print the outcome/last one!

```
lst = []
for num in range(0,6):
    lst.append(num)
print(lst) # Un-indent :D
```

Happy Coding, good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a *for output* to the list, your code was correct. You only put "print" in the wrong place.

Just replace this:

```
lst = []
for num in range(0,6):
    lst.append(num)
    print(lst)
```

to this:

```
lst = []
for num in range(0,6):
    lst.append(num)
print(lst)
```

But there are more effective ways to make a list from numbers range, it was displayed in other comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `print` inside for loop in your code is called for every value of `num`, that means you begin the for loop, you add `num` to `lst`and you print `lst`.
The solution is print `lst` after adding all value of `num` to `lst`, you can put `print` outside of `for`

```
lst = []
for num in range(0,6):
    lst.append(num)
print(lst)
```